# How to create comparison validator MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i have 2 properties
int MinValue
int MaxValue
I have to  create a data annotation attribute to validate this
it should say
1)"MinValue should be less than MaxValue" if  MinValue and MaxValue  are not zero.
2)it should not compare the two values if both  MinValue and MaxValue are zero(0).

any input from  you to achieve this will help me sure in doing this

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom validator attribute deriving from [ValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CustomValidateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var model = (MyModel)value;
        return model.MinValue < model.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

And decorate your model with this custom attribute:

```
[CustomValidate]
public class MyModel
{
    public decimal MinValue { get; set; }
    public decimal MaxValue { get; set; }
}
```